# For A,B,C,and D sets. Is it true that $(A - C) \times (B - D) \subset (A \times B) - (C \times D)$ proof verification

Tags: elementary-set-theory, self-learning

I claim that $(A - C)  \times (B - D) \subset  (A \times B) - (C \times D)$.

Let $(x,y) \in (A - C)  \times (B - D)$. It means that $x \in (A - C)$ and $y \in (B - D)$. This implies that $x \in A$ and $y \in B$ such that $x$ and $y$ doesn't exist in C and D respectively. Therefore $(A - C)  \times (B - D) \subset  (A \times B) - (C \times D)$.

I haven't found counter example yet but it should be true that this is strict inclusion.

Comment: Try with a simple example, $A=B=\{1,2\}, C=D=\{2\}$. There is an inconsistency between the title and the text.

Comment: If you want to create your own counterexample, think like this: $(c, d)\notin C\times D$ does NOT require $c\notin C$ AND $d\notin D$. Therefore, if you could find sets $A,B,C,D$ such that there exists some $(a, b)\in A\times B$ with $a\in C$ and $b\notin D$, then you are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $C = \emptyset$, and $A,B,D$ non-empty with $B = D$, you get

$(A \setminus C) \times (B \setminus D) = \emptyset \subsetneq A \times B = (A \times B) \setminus (C \times D)$